# Convert Excel Range to ADO.NET DataSet or DataTable, etc

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, range

I have an Excel spreadsheet that will sit out on a network share drive.  It needs to be accessed by my Winforms C# 3.0 application (many users could be using the app and hitting this spreadsheet at the same time).  There is a lot of data on one worksheet.  This data is broken out into areas that I have named as ranges.  I need to be able to access these ranges individually, return each range as a dataset, and then bind it to a grid.

I have found examples that use OLE and have got these to work.  However, I have seen some warnings about using this method, plus at work we have been using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as the standard thus far.  I don't really want to stray from this unless I have to.  Our users will be using Office 2003 on up as far as I know.

I can get the range I need with the following code:

```
MyDataRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)
    MyWorkSheet.get_Range("MyExcelRange", Type.Missing);
```

The OLE way was nice as it would take my first row and turn those into columns.  My ranges (12 total) are for the most part different from each other in number of columns.  Didn't know if this info would affect any recommendations.

Is there any way to use Interop and get the returned range back into a dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about a built-in function, but it shouldn't be difficult to write it yourself. Pseudocode:

```
DataTable MakeTableFromRange(Range range)
{
   table = new DataTable
   for every column in range
   {
      add new column to table
   }
   for every row in range
   {
      add new datarow to table
      for every column in range
      {
         table.cells[column, row].value = range[column, row].value
      }
   }
   return table
}
```

Comment: I appreciate all the responses.  Since I couldn't find anything built-in, I went ahead and just rolled through the range and created a datatable on-the-fly.  All the suggestions listed here would really work, it's just that I didn't want to use OLEDB and I can't bring in a 3rd party library at this point.  Thank you for your fast responses.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what type of data you have.But for an excel data like shown in this link http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?f8d4ef4173.png, you can use the following code to load into data table.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
       try
       {        
            DataTable sheetTable = loadSingleSheet(@"C:\excelFile.xls", "Sheet1$");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = sheetTable;
       }
       catch (Exception Ex)
       {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "");
       }  
    }        

    private OleDbConnection returnConnection(string fileName)
    {
        return new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;\"");
    }

    private DataTable loadSingleSheet(string fileName, string sheetName)
    {           
        DataTable sheetData = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = this.returnConnection(fileName))
        {
           conn.Open();
           // retrieve the data using data adapter
           OleDbDataAdapter sheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "]", conn);
            sheetAdapter.Fill(sheetData);
        }                        
        return sheetData;
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate the code and OLEDB definitely makes it easy, but I need to stick with the Excel Interop for now.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to take a look at [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) when it comes to read/write Excel 2003 XLS files. NPOI is a life saver.

I think you'll have to iterate your range and create DataRows to put in your DataTable.

This question on StackOverflow provides more resources:

[Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/151005/114029)

Comment: I will keep this in mind for future projects.  As of now I can't introduce a new library into our application.

Answer (score 0):

This method does not work well when the same column in the excel spread sheet contains both text and numbers. For instance, if `Range("A3")=Hello` and `Range("A7")=5` then it reads only Hello and the value for `Range("A7")` is `DBNULL`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
   try
   {        
        DataTable sheetTable = loadSingleSheet(@"C:\excelFile.xls", "Sheet1$");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = sheetTable;
   }
   catch (Exception Ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "");
   }  
}        

private OleDbConnection returnConnection(string fileName)
{
    return new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;\"");
}

private DataTable loadSingleSheet(string fileName, string sheetName)
{           
    DataTable sheetData = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection conn = this.returnConnection(fileName))
    {
       conn.Open();
       // retrieve the data using data adapter
       OleDbDataAdapter sheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "]", conn);
        sheetAdapter.Fill(sheetData);
    }                        
    return sheetData;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made method which can take alredy **filtered** data from Excel
Taking filtered data in *Range* format

```
        Worksheet sheet = null;
        sheet = (Worksheet)context.cDocumentExcel.Sheets[requiredSheetName];

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sheet.Activate();
        sheet.UsedRange.Select();
        List<Range> ranges = new List<Range>();
        Range usedrange = sheet.UsedRange;

        foreach (var oneRange in usedrange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible))
        {
            ranges.Add(oneRange);
        }


        dt = (_makeTableFromRange(ranges));
```

Converting from Range to DataTable

```
 private static DataTable _makeTableFromRange(List<Range> ranges)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();


        foreach (var range in ranges)
        {
            while (table.Columns.Count < range.Column)
            {
                table.Columns.Add();
            }

            while (table.Rows.Count < range.Row)
            {
                table.Rows.Add();
            }

            table.Rows[range.Row - 1][range.Column - 1] = range.Value2;
        }


        //clean from empty rows
        var filteredRows = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().
                        Where(row => !row.ItemArray.All(field => field is System.DBNull ||
                                                                 string.Compare((field as string).Trim(), string.Empty) ==
                                                                 0));
        table = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
        return table;
    }
```