# Save Excel to CSV pipe separated (XlFileFormat enumeration)

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I would like to save xls or xlsx files to a csv extension pipe separated. The following code I use, the XlFileFormat is only possible to save it as an csv comma separated as you can see on the Microsoft [info page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx).

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
var excel = new Application();
var wbk = excel.Workbooks.Open(sourceFileLocation, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
wbk.SaveAs(targetFileLocation, XlFileFormat.xlCSVMac, AccessMode: XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive);
```

I could save it with a comma sperated and open the file again and change all commas in a pipe, but this is an ugly way. Is there another **easy way** to save the document to a pipe separated CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you combine
[Convert Excel Range to ADO.NET DataSet or DataTable, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458481/convert-excel-range-to-ado-net-dataset-or-datatable-etc)

and

[Convert DataTable to CSV stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888181/convert-datatable-to-csv-stream)

to read the data into a ADO.Net data table and save it in CSV format with the flexibility you need.

Comment: Isn't DataSets and DataTables an old technology? I still hear my teacher telling me to not use these anymore. But yeah I would also not know another way...

Comment: I would advise you to accept such claims without questioning them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698151/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net-with-stored-procedures

Comment: I meant, I would advise you **not** accept such claims without questioning them :-)